# DropDown menu with Scroll View in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a DropDown menu with scroll view but I just achieved that scroll down is Horizontal... but not Vertical.

Also I don't know how to make that after choosing a option from menu it stays that option..
For example if I choose POLAND I want to that option be firs and display Poland.

**HTML code.**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Country</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" 
onkeyup="filterFunction()">

<a href="#about">Albania <img src="themes/images/flags/Albania.png" 
width="25" height="6" alt=""/></a>

 <a href="#about">Andorra <img src="themes/images/flags/Andorra.png" 
width="25" height="6" alt=""/></a>

  <a href="#about">Argentina <img src="themes/images/flags/Argentina.png" 
width="25" height="6" alt=""/></a>

   <a href="#about">Austria <img src="themes/images/flags/Austria.png" 
width="25" height="6" alt=""/></a>

    <a href="#about">Poland <img src="themes/images/flags/Poland.png" 
width="25" height="6" alt=""/></a>

</div>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT code**

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;

position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
width: 160px;
overflow:scroll;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;

}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}



.show {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're going is going to be almost impossible to maintain because you'll be changing the order of the html items on every key up and thats not great. A better idea would be having the data separated in an array and display according to user search.

I've made a quick jsfiddle for you, please take a look:

```
`var items = [
    { country: "Albania" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Albannn1ia" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Albdorra" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Albrgentina" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Austria" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Portugal" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Poland" , href: "#about" },
    { country: "Polonia" , href: "#about" }
];
var chosenItems = items;
https://jsfiddle.net/gugalondon/5cny3qxr/4/`
```